# Is there a better way of accessing ArrayList object elements?

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

Took me a bit to figure this out but Im just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this

this is the gist of my main

```
public class Main {

    private static Bank Chase = new Bank();

    //This is the function in main to add a transaction to a specified customer of a branch

    public static void addTransaction() {

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the branch");
        String branch = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to add");
        double amount = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine();

        Chase.getBranchList().get(Chase.branchIndex(branch)).getCustomerList().get(Chase.getBranchList().get(Chase.branchIndex(branch)).customerIndex(name)).addTransaction(amount);
    }
}
```

This last line is really long and confusing to others this is what it does

```
//gets the branchlist -> gets the specified branch -> gets the customerlist -> finds the specified customer -> adds transaction
```

these are the other relevant parts of the classes the function references

```
public class Bank {

    private ArrayList<Branch> branchList = new ArrayList<Branch>();

    public ArrayList<Branch> getBranchList() {
        return branchList;
    }
    public int branchIndex(String name){
        for(Branch branch: branchList){
        if(branch.getName().equals(name)){
            return branchList.indexOf(branch);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

public class Branch {

    private String branchName;
    private ArrayList<Customer> customerList;

    public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }
    public int customerIndex(String name){
        for(Customer customer: customerList){
            if(customer.getName().equals(name)){
                return customerList.indexOf(customer);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

public class Customer {

    private String customerName;
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions = new ArrayList<Double>();


 public Customer(String customerName, double amount) {

        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.transactions = new ArrayList<Double>();
        transactions.add(amount);
    }
    public String getName() {

        return customerName;
    }

    public void addTransaction(double transaction){

        transactions.add(transaction);
    }
}
```

So is there any more readable way of accessing these elements that are in object ArrayLists? I think the last line in addTransaction() looks a bit redundant.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: Try using local variables and java.util.Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than one long line you could

a) split the code into multiple lines

```
Chase.getBranchList().get(Chase.branchIndex(branch))
                     .getCustomerList()
                     .get(Chase.getBranchList()
                         .get(Chase.branchIndex(branch))
                         .customerIndex(name))
                     .addTransaction(amount);
```

b) stored the returned values of each get into a local variable, especially the code that it re-calling the same methods e.g. `Chase.branchIndex(branch)` and `Chase.getBranchList()`

Comment: For your b) answer would the changes reflect back to the actual elements? I learned c/c++ first so. How does java know that these need to be reflected back into the actual ArrayList objects?

Comment: Zain - what do you mean?

Comment: sorry newbie here accidentally tried to format my comment and ended up posting it

Comment: If you get an mutable object from a List and modify it, then the change will be saved

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are assuming unique customer/branch names, and then cycling through your array list to find the customer by name. This assumption is fine, if it's a valid assumption but could mean that there are more optimal solutions. I would recommend a refactor of your code to utilise a java hash map:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Basically, this will mean that you can access the customer/bank directly by name and will simplify your code greatly! It will also have performance benefits.

For your scenario this refactor would look similar to this:

```
public class Branch
{
    private HashMap<String, Customer> _customers;
    private String _branchName;

    public Branch(String branchName)
    {
        _branchName = branchName;
        _customers = new HashMap<String, Customer>();
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(String customerName)
    {
        return _customers.get(customerName);
    }
}
```

If you follow the same for Bank, you should be able to access a Customer and add a transaction as follows:

```
Chase.getBranch(branch).getCustomer(name).addTransaction(transaction);
```

Let me know if you need help converting Bank :)

Comment: I am in a class that's going by topic, hash mapping is not covered yet so i'm not allowed to use those.but I will try this out on my own! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zain,

You could also just change Branch so that the customerIndex method becomes getCustomer and when you find a customer with a matching name when looping through your for loop, you return the customer. It would have a similar effect in terms of simplicity of code but you could use the array list as the underlying data structure. The same could be done for Bank and the branchIndex method.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you've got some minor design flaws.

**Step 1:** Add a method called `getBranchByName(String branchName)` to your `Bank` class that returns a `Branch` object and get rid of your `branchIndex()` method:

```
public Branch getBranchByName(String branchName) {
        return branchList.stream()
                .filter(branch -> branch.getBranchName().equals(branchName))
                .findAny()
                .get();
    }
```

**Step 2:** Add a method called `getCustomerByName(String name)` to your `Customer` class that returns a `Customer` object and get rid of your `customerIndex()` method:

```
public Customer getCustomerByName(String name) {
        return customerList.stream()
                .filter(customer -> customer.getCustomerName().equals(name))
                .findAny()
                .get();
    }
```

**Step 3:** Now, method call in your `main()` method becomes more compact, simple and easy to read:

```
Chase.getBranchByName(branchName).getCustomerByName(customerName).addTransaction(amount);
```

**Note:** I've used **Java 8 streams** as you can observe. If you are not allowed to use Java 8 streams, you can just stick with classic **imperative style** of programming by writing `for()` loops as you have done earlier. As a quick example, if you want to write `getBranchByName(String branchName)` in old fashioned **Java 7** style, your loop looks like this:

```
for(Branch branch : branchList) {
        if(branch.getBranchName().equals(branchName)){
                return branch;
        }   
}
```